# How to get fast output in which calculation part has to be done by clicking button in Android?

Tags: java, android, button, loading

My Problem is while clicking the button it goes to next Activity during that time it takes nearly 10-12 secs for loading the values in next activity.Please help me from this issue and suggestions will be appreciable.

**Here is the code:**

```
Button  mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pay);
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
public void onClick(View view)
  {
    Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,second.class);
    i.putExtra("rate", rate);                      
    startActivity(i);
  }
});
```

so during clicking the button the calculation part is also working. Help me out from this.

Comment: Where are you doing the calculations now??

Comment: im doing the calculations for the calculator app Here the max years for the app is 50yrs if we select in that condition it takes lots of time to load. @RKN

Comment: Better do the calculations in AsyncTask when the button is clicked, so that you can display that **Loading...** progress bar and in `onPostExecute()`, you can call the 2nd activity, that way user will have at least some idea that some process is going on.

Comment: you are calculate your value in second.java if yes then you have to calculate value in mainactivity and then pass value to second screen and just display it.

Comment: if you are already work with my previous comment then you have to wait for some second to start new activity.

Comment: yes thanks @Pallavi implemented the same the progress bar and one more doubt i dont know exactly can we reduce the delay time of calculation part.

Comment: yes waiting time is showing to user in the form of progress bar  as loading..! @Harshid

Answer (score 0):

No sure what you are trying to do....

In your onClick() method, you are starting new activity so obviously it will go to new Activity. Why don't you do the calculations in onClick method itself and update the values displayed?

Comment: yeah actually the method will be called there and i want to reduce the  loading time if i click the button @Zaki Anwar Hamdani